# Adding/removing classes cause input content to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
    <div
    className={classNames(styles["login"], {
      [styles["login-top"]]: moveControlsTo === MOVE_CONTROLS_TO.TOP,
      [styles["login-fixed"]]: !(moveControlsTo === MOVE_CONTROLS_TO.TOP),
    })}
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      id="freesearch-input"
      className={classNames(styles["freesearch-input"], styles["borders"])}
      autoComplete={"off"}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      value={""}
    />
  </div>
```

A simple div with a input on it. The problem is when the classname of this div is changing from login-top to login-fixed or vice versa the input value disappear and I don't want this behaviour.
There is a solution for that ?

Comment: use `defaultValue` and if a rerender still happens, add a `key={}` to something that does not change. as it is, you're binding the value to an empty string so every time the component renders due to whatever change, it restores the input to what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content disappears because whenever the state changes your component rerenders. You are setting the value of the input field as `value={""}`. Therefore it loads empty every time.
Just make a state for this input element and change it on the change as.

```
const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");

<input onChange={(evt)=>setInputVal(evt.target.val)} value={inputVal}>
```

Now, whenever the state changes, your input will always show `inputVal` value.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The value is still lost when classname is changed.

Comment: Kindly check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-wildflower-fd66g?file=/src/App.js

It is similar to your changes.
Or if you have online sandbox, I can check there.

Comment: My bad I did something wrong. It works now. Thanks